# multiple tables OR clause and with alias

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart

I need to query two columns "oc_filter_group_description.name" and "oc_filter.name" and get all matching results.
The alias seems to be causing me the problem. I've tried using a sub query but being a complete novice I really don't know what I'm doing.
 
Here is the code as it stands. The OR clause is what needs adapting

```
SELECT *,(SELECT name FROM oc_filter_group_description fgd 

WHERE f.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id) AS `group` 

FROM oc_filter f LEFT JOIN oc_filter_description fd ON (f.filter_id = fd.filter_id)

WHERE fd.name LIKE '% **QUERY GOES HERE** %'

OR 'group' LIKE '% **QUERY GOES HERE** %'
```

I have spent far too long trying to get this to work I thought I better call in re-enforcements. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: try removing the single quotation mark and just group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference column aliases defined in the `select` in the `where` clause.  This is your query:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT name
        FROM oc_filter_group_description fgd 
        WHERE f.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id
       ) AS `group` 
FROM oc_filter f LEFT JOIN
     oc_filter_description fd
     ON f.filter_id = fd.filter_id
WHERE fd.name LIKE '% **QUERY GOES HERE** %' OR
      'group' LIKE '% **QUERY GOES HERE** %';
```

It has two obvious problems.  The first is that `'group'` is a string constant not a column reference.  *Only* use single quotes for string literals.  It avoids this type of problem.  The second is that it refers to the `group` defined in the `select` clause.

The best solution is to replace the subquery in the `select` with another `join`:

```
SELECT *, fgd.name as group_name
FROM oc_filter f LEFT JOIN
     oc_filter_description fd
     ON f.filter_id = fd.filter_id LEFT JOIN
     oc_filter_group_description fgd 
     ON f.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id
WHERE fd.name LIKE '% **QUERY GOES HERE** %' OR
      fgd.name LIKE '% **QUERY GOES HERE** %';
```

Note that I also changed the name `group` to `group_name`, so it doesn't conflict with a MySQL reserved words.  Voila, no quotes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

This might look a minor thing, but you shouldn't use backticks and whenever possible avoid keywords:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT name FROM oc_filter_group_description fgd
    WHERE f.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id) AS T_GROUP
FROM oc_filter f LEFT JOIN oc_filter_description fd ON (f.filter_id = fd.filter_id)
WHERE fd.name LIKE '% **QUERY GOES HERE** %'
OR T_GROUP LIKE '% **QUERY GOES HERE** %'
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You made it much more complicated than necessary.  All you need is something like this:

```
select just the fields you need
from oc_filter f LEFT JOIN oc_filter_description fd ON (f.filter_id = fd.filter_id)
and (fd.name like '%static text goes here, not a query%'
or `group` like '%static text goes here, not a query%')
```

Notice that the filters are now part of the join as opposed to a where clause.  If they were in a where clause, the left join would effectively become an inner join.